# How to get file as a resource with Storage?

Tags: laravel, file, laravel-storage

I am trying to lock a file with the *flock* function but I am not able to do it. I work with Laravel 8 and Storage Class.

The code is as follows:

```
$disk = Storage::disk('communication');
$file_name = 'received.json';

$file_exists = $disk->exists($file_name);
if($file_exists){
    flock($disk->get($file_name), LOCK_EX);
    ...
}
```

The problem I'm having is that when I invoke the get() function on the file path, it returns the contents of the file (a string), which causes the following error:

> flock() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

I need to know how to get file as a resource and not the content of the file.
Could someone help me and tell me how to do it?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: try  this. .
if($file_exists){
$fileContent= Storage::disk('communication')->get($file_name);
    flock($fileContent, LOCK_EX);

}

Comment: Thanks for the comment John. That's exactly what I'm doing. I tried anyway and the result (the error) is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Storage::readStream()` method

```
   if($file_exists){
    
      $stream=Storage::disk('communication')->readStream($file_name); 
       flock($stream, LOCK_EX);
    
    }
```

As per php doc

```
flock(resource $stream, int $operation, int &$would_block = null): bool
```

> First param needed stream.flock() allows you to perform a simple
> reader/writer model which can be used on virtually every platform
> (including most Unix derivatives and even Windows).

Ref:https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php